# Zxing with Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, zxing

I am using zxing Framework in my new project for QRcode scanning.
I followed all the instructions from this link give bu google
 http://zxing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/iphone/README.
But still its throwing errors below

Build target BusinessCard of project BusinessCard with configuration Debug

> Ld /Users/innoppltechnologies/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BusinessCard-gapnbrefvettfmgtnizgctiusbsn/Build/Intermediates/BusinessCard.build/Debug-iphoneos/BusinessCard.build/Objects-normal/armv6/BusinessCard normal armv6
>       cd /Users/innoppltechnologies/iosapps/BusinessCard
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0
>       setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk -L/Users/innoppltechnologies/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BusinessCard-gapnbrefvettfmgtnizgctiusbsn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib -L/Users/innoppltechnologies/iosapps/BusinessCard -
>   Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
>     "_CVPixelBufferGetHeight", referenced from:
>         -[ZXingWidgetController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
>     "_kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey", referenced from:
>         -[ZXingWidgetController initCapture] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
>     "_CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress", referenced from:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: it is not aqn answer but when you do not find solution try out http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/ i using it and i m satisfide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you referenced all the frameworks to the project?

Make sure these frameworks are added:

**a. AVFoundation** <- This is probably the one which is causing the prob for you. Make sure this is added.

b. AudioToolbox

**c. CoreVideo** <- This is second culprit. Check if this is added

**d. CoreMedia** <- This is second culprit as well. Check if this is added

e. libiconv

f. AddressBook

g. AddressBookUI

Answer (score 3):

You not properly install Zxing library. You downloaded zxing library from your given link is properly working. Please check out your project setting.